# How do I retrieve data from my database?

Tags: php, html, database, hybrid-mobile-app

I am trying to retrieve data from my database using php... Currently I have 2 submit buttons which you click to retrieve the data. One to bring back case studies and one to bring back images.'retrieve.php' code retrieve's data from a table called 'P_CASE_STUDIES' and this works. However when I try to retrieve the content from the second table called 'P_IMAGES'... it doesn't display. Can someone tell me what im doing wrong.

**Here is the code for my images.php page:**

```
<?php

function images ()
{

    // Connect to the SQL DB
    $conn = new SQL_connection("webservice");
    $conn->connect();

    // Create SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM P_IMAGES";

    // Execute query
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn->link(), $sql );

    // Loop over all result rows
    $result_array = array();

    while( $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) 
    {

        $result_array[] = $post;

    }

    // Write to JSON
    header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
    echo json_encode( $result_array );

}
```

**Here is the code for my retrieve.php (P_CASE_STUDIES):**

```
<?php

function retrieve ()
{

    // Connect to the SQL DB
    $conn = new SQL_connection("webservice");
    $conn->connect();

    // Create SQL query
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM P_CASE_STUDIES;";

    // Execute query
    $result = mysqli_query( $conn->link(), $sql );

    // Loop over all result rows
    $result_array = array();

    while( $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) 
    {

        $result_array[] = $post;

    }

    // Write to JSON
    header( 'Content-type: application/json' );
    echo json_encode( $result_array );

}
```

**Web services page:**

```
<?php

    class  Webservice
    {

        var $link;

        //Switch statement to call relevant function

        function __construct() 
        {

            require __DIR__."/sql_connection.php";

            switch ($_POST['action'])
            {

            case 'retrieve':
                require "retrieve.php";
                retrieve();
                break;

            case 'images':
                require "images.php";
                images();
                break;

            default:
                echo "Error";
                break;
            }

        }


    }

    $go = new Webservice();

?>
```

**And finally my index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">
    <title>Pinder</title>

    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="webservice.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>

                    <td><input name="action" value="retrieve" type="hidden"></td>

                    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" class="button"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>



                <form action="webservice.php" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr>

                    <td><input name="action" value="images" type="hidden"></td>

                    <td><input type="submit" value="submit" class="button"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: `it doesn't display`. What does it not display? You could add some more echo() statements to see how the script and the query is executed.

Comment: What would be the result of json_encode() if the array was empty? You would still receive something i think.

Comment: @greenapps see the thing is I don't know where to echo... im new to php! This bit of code is put together by sources from the internet

Comment: You can put echo() statements where you want. It's just like a Print() or Log.d().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are replacing the array each time with $post

A question! How many rows are there actually in P_CASE_STUDIES?

```
while( $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) 
{

    $result_array[] = $post;

}
```

Should be something like:

```
var i = 0;
while( $post = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $result ) ) 
{

   $result_array[$i] = $post;
   $i++;
}
```

Comment: The i is not needed ofcourse. But you could echo() it to see the number of rows while debugging.

Comment: @greenapps on another somewhere else there is a function to upload images... the rows will never stop.

Comment: No I've just found out the code is fine... it just won't retrieve the image's because the file is too large... Loooking into how to resolve this now

Comment: Ok. I hope you solve it :D Internet is your friend :D

Comment: @TheGarrett. Please do not mark this answer as correct. As you said yourself it has nothing to do with your problem. Better answer it yourself and mark that.